# vue v-for of typescript enum

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Why does this `v-for` loop over an `enum` show the names *and* values?

How can I iterate only over the keys?

```js
export enum Colors {
  "RED" = 1,
  "BLUE" =  2,
  "GREEN" = 3,
}
```

```html
<template>
   <div>
      <v-chip v-for="key in Colors" :key="key">{{key}}</v-chip>
   </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {Colors} from "./Enums"
import Vue from "vue";
export default Vue.extend({
  data: () => ({
     Colors,
  }),
});
</script>
```

This strangely results in 6 chips, but I would expect only 3.

- RED
- BLUE
- GREEN
- 1
- 2
- 3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a simple way to get a list of keys/numbers from enum in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413651/is-there-a-simple-way-to-get-a-list-of-keys-numbers-from-enum-in-typescript)

Comment: I think you have declared enum `Colors` as an `Object`.

Comment: @MattU no, `Object.keys()` doesn't fix this.

Comment: No, but it answers the question almost exactly as the answer on this question did. It still mentions how to filter the keys (e.g. filter out numeric keys).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [`v-for` lists all properties of an object](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-object), it will show both the *forward and reverse properties* of the Typescript enum. You'll need to [filter](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/list.html#displaying-filtered-sorted-results) the keys yourself, possibly using [Number.isInteger()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger).

For context, [Typescript enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) get [reverse mappings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings) by default:

> In addition to creating an object with property names for members, numeric enums members also get a reverse mapping from enum values to enum names. For example, in this example:
>
> ```js
> enum Enum {
>   A,
> }
>
> let a = Enum.A;
> let nameOfA = Enum[a]; // "A"
> ```
>
> TypeScript compiles this down to the following JavaScript:
>
> ```
> "use strict";
> var Enum;
> (function (Enum) {
>   Enum[Enum["A"] = 0] = "A";
> })(Enum || (Enum = {}));
> let a = Enum.A;
> let nameOfA = Enum[a]; // "A"
> ```
>
> In this generated code, an enum is compiled into an object that stores both forward (`name -> value`) and reverse (`value -> name`) mappings. References to other enum members are always emitted as property accesses and never inlined.

Comment: Thanks - how would I iterate over only the values? I've tried Object.keys/values and still get duplicated

Comment: Sorry, I'd overlooked that part originally. You'll need to filter the keys yourself, possibly using [Number.isInteger()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger).

Comment: @JeffBowman You could use v-for="(value, key, index) in myEnum" to have access to the values

Comment: @Tibike No, that's not the point. The point is that in a TypeScript enum we see Enum[Key]=Value *and* Enum[Value]=Key. Like my original syntax, your syntax would show both directions, which is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: @JeffBowman My mistake, my example used string literals for values not numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on **Jeff's** answer, the code will look something like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <v-chip 
        v-for="([value, key], idx) in Object.entries(Colors).filter(([_, k]) => Number.isInteger(k))" 
        :key="idx"
      >
        {{ key }}
      </v-chip>
    </div>
</template>
```